# Convert 0V - 5V voltage to 0-1V for ADC (for ESP8266 12F)

Tags: arduino, embedded, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, adc

I am using force sensor for measuring its value through the ADC of Arduino. Here I am supplying 5V on a force sensor and a 3.3k resistor for pulldown. I'm converting that input raw ADC value (range 0-1023) to weight through some coding.

I need to remove the Arduino and connect the force sensor directly to ESP8266 12F and use its ADC to measure the voltage. But the problem is its range is only 0-1V. I have tried some voltage dividers and made 1V from the 5V supply at the back, now the ADC value has a range of 0-90, using the map function of Arduino I converted that 0-90 back to 0-1023.
Here is the coding for 5V:

```
fsrADC = analogRead(A0);                      
float fsrV = fsrADC * VCC / 1023.0;         //VCC = 5
float fsrR = R_DIV * (VCC / fsrV - 1.0);    //R_Div = 3300 for 3.3k pulldown
```

Here is the coding for 1V:

```
fsrADC = analogRead(A0);        
fsrADC = map(fsrADC,0,90,0,1000);              
float fsrV = fsrADC * VCC / 1023.0;         //VCC = 5
float fsrR = R_DIV * (VCC / fsrV - 1.0);    //R_Div = 3300 for 3.3k pulldown
```

After this there are a few more lines which converts this resistance to weight. As you can see I need 0-1023 range of input analog value for the next line to work properly.
The calculated weight is not accurate. I think its the problem of supply because I am converting the 5V supply to 1V through a voltage divider and using its output to a sensor. Any suggestions and a good voltage divided circuit?

Comment: Somethings wrong with your adc; which should range from 0-1023, not to just 90. you also don't need the 2nd line in your "1V" version, which should in total, basically just be `(adc/1023) * VCC`

Comment: I know this is an old post but the correct solution here (in addition to the voltage divider) is to feed the 1V to your ADC voltage ref. If you keep that one at 5V but only feed it values between 0-1V, you toss all of your measurement resolution out the window. Also, using floating point on a 8 bit MCU isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea in comparing to 1.0V.  But you need to compare the ADC value to a more suitable reference voltage as [described in the documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogReference).  Ideally you'd use `EXTERNAL` 1.0V reference applied to the `AREF` pin, though the 1.1V reference might yield pretty good results too with proper software scaling.  Reference voltage is the key.  As far as voltage divider circuits go, just google them, it's a super-simple circuit provided you have the right resistors.  Once you get very near 1.0V, apply that to `AREF` and set up that as your reference according to the documentation.